# How to broadcast message to everybody in the room with Socket.io

Tags: websocket, server, socket.io, client, communication

I am trying to create a custom room with socket.io, but haven't had much luck yet. I can communicate between my server and client, the problem only comes, when I try to use rooms. The following is my implementation:

Client side:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected');
            socket.emit('room', 'hello');
        });

socket.on('message', function(data) {
            console.log('Incoming message:', data);
        });

socket.open();
```

Server side:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} connected.`);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} disconnected.`);
    });

    socket.on('room', function(msg) {
        socket.join('room', () => {
            socket.to('room').emit('message', "wohoo");
        });
    });
});
```

I receive the message and join the room from the server side, but the emitted message in the room is never received by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to get the room message code, I think this would be helpful to you.

https://github.com/JSbotHQ/RealTime-Socket.IO/tree/master/ExpressJS

And to test out your SocketIO events you can use this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firecamp/eajaahbjpnhghjcdaclbkeamlkepinbl